# Are the real and imaginary parts of an invertible matrix has to be invertible too?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{N}$ be a complex matrix. Assuming that its inverse exists. Does it imply that both $\mathbf{A}_{R}^{-1}$ and $\mathbf{A}_{I}^{-1}$ exist? where $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}_{R} + i\mathbf{A}_{I}$. If not, can you give a counter-example?

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&i\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: cool example. it turns out $\mathbf{A}$ invertible is equivalent to $\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A}_{R} & \mathbf{A}_{I} \\ \mathbf{A}_{I} & \mathbf{A}_{R} \end{bmatrix}$ invertible.

Comment: @Peter one of the $A_I$ should be negative

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not: For any real matrix $\bf A$ (including invertible ones) viewed as a complex matrix, ${\bf A}_I = {\bf 0}$.